# Qml rounded corner of one side with border

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Is there a way to have a `Rectangle` with one side rounded edges and also a border in Qt without using the `Canvas`.

Something like below.

[image]

I did try below code and I am able to create the rounded corner on one side.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    visible: true

    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 50
        opacity: 0.5
        layer.enabled: true
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            radius: 10
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
        }
    }
}
```

With above code I am able to get the one side rounded corners but when I add border then I see overlapping borders.
Is there a clean way of doing this in Qml?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do that.

1. Not the "cleanest" way, but probably the simplest performance-wise. You can keep using the code you have above, but just draw another non-bordered rectangle that covers up the extra border line that you are seeing.

```
    property int borderWidth: 4
    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 50
        opacity: 0.5
        layer.enabled: true
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: roundCorners
            color: "blue"
            radius: 10
            border.width: borderWidth
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: squareCorners
            color: "blue"
            border.width: borderWidth
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
        }
        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: squareCorners.left
            anchors.verticalCenter: squareCorners.verticalCenter
            width: borderWidth
            height: squareCorners.height - borderWidth * 2
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
```

2. You can use QML's `Shape` object and use a `ShapePath` to define it. The docs can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html).

```
Shape {
    ShapePath {
        strokeWidth: 4
        strokeColor: "black"
        fillColor: "blue"
        PathLine { ... }
        PathLine { ... }
        PathLine { ... }
        PathArc { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Third option would be Canvas, but that's not so performant (so I'm not going to write an answer for that)

Comment: @Amfasis, right, plus the OP said they didn't want to use `Canvas`.

Comment: lol, didn't read that

Comment: @JarMan, would you mind giving a fully working example of approach #2, with the ShapePath?